# How to keep "new solution explorer views" after reload a project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

Every time I load my project I do organize my workspace into 3 "new solution explorer view". One Solution Explorer for the views folder, one for the models folder and the last one for the controllers folder.

However when I close and reopen my project it is set back to the default workspace. Is possible to keep those created solution explorer views ?

The Save workspace option don't work with multiples solutions explorers.

Comment: Are you running VS in Admin-Mode?

Comment: I'm not @lokusking

Comment: Well i would try that in first place

Comment: it Don't work @lokusking

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the short answer is "you can't".  I have been attempting to find a solution utilising the MS Macro addin, and some of the other tools available, but none of them seems to be able to automate the opening of additional solution views, let alone a way of persisting them once they are set up.

I was quite surprised that the "Save Window Layout" feature in VS2015 doesn't allow you to do this either.  It simply ignores any additional solution views.  My theory on this is that, as the views are solution specific, it doesn't make sense to have them persisted as a default for the entire environment.

Comment: whats so harm or challenging in managing project basis? there is anyway .suo file for each project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather dirty solution I came up with in the last hour. It uses an AutoHotKey script which does what you would do by hand. The case in the code is quite specific, since I want to open two panes on top of each other each one searching for a specific search term, but you can easily modify the code to suit your needs.

---

### What I want to end up with

[image: What I want to end up with]

### Usage

Have the solution Explorer on Docked Mode and on "Show all Files" view. Double click the script, which should have the ending `.ahk` with AutoHotKey installed. You have 2 seconds to Alt+Tab to Visual Studio, where the script will do it's thing. When it is done, close the original Solution Explorer by hand.

### The Script

```
FolderPos           = 2 ; Position of Target Folder, Example in the picture below

XPosFirst           = 24 ; How many times to press right
YPosFirst           = 42 ; How many times to press down
SearchTermFirst     = "cpp" ; Text to search in the explorer

XPosSecond          = 22
YPosSecond          = 13
SearchTermSecond    = "hpp"

InitiateMove() {
    Send !{Space}
    Send M
}
NewSolutionExplorer() {
    Send {AppsKey}
    Send N
}

ExitSearch() {
    Send {Down}
    Send {Up 5}
    Send {Down}
}

BlockInput MouseMove
Sleep 2000

SetKeyDelay 10
Send ^!l
Send {Down %FolderPos%}

NewSolutionExplorer()
SetKeyDelay 80
InitiateMove()

Send {Right %XPosFirst%}
Send {Down %YPosFirst%}

SetKeyDelay 10
Send {Enter}
Send ^;
Send %SearchTermFirst%
ExitSearch()

NewSolutionExplorer()
SetKeyDelay 80
InitiateMove()

Send {Right %XPosSecond%}
Send {Down %YPosSecond%}

SetKeyDelay 10
Send {Enter}
Send ^;
Send %SearchTermSecond%
ExitSearch()

BlockInput MouseMoveOff
ExitApp
```

---

### `FolderPos` Example: Folder src is on position 2

[image: <code>FolderPos</code> Example: Folder src is on position 2]

Comment: Can it be made less "dirty"?  It's certainly an answer better than, "Can't do it." :)

Comment: @FauChristian I'm not sure. I find it really weird that there are no shortcuts for snapping the window to dockable areas, rather you have to move it manually a couple pixels at a time...

Answer (score 1):

For VS2017 and VS2019 I found extension ['Multiple Solution Explorer Tools'](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misaz.multiplesolutionexplorertools). Only problem - it does not maintain view windows position and size after load.

Comment: *Update* Version 1.2 supports vs2019 **but** it didn't work as of jan-2020 (the author says its working on it)